# MeshLab: take a snapshot from command line

Tags: command-line, import, 3d, meshlab

I've to import a PLY mesh to MeshLab and take a snapshot from command line. How to do this?

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to perform a snapshot from command line ? Thank